# ios 10.0.1 does not play video within webviews

Tags: ios, video, youtube, uiwebview

As soon as I updated the iOS version from 9.x to 10.0.1 all my apps don't play youtube videos anymore (UIWebView).

I'm using the youtube sdk

```
pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', '~> 0.1.6'
```

the player starts with the following method, and it works with all previous os version.

```
[self.ytPlayer loadWithVideoId:[self getYouTubeIdFromUrlStr:urlStr] playerVars:playerVars];
```

The log shows the following rows many times.

```
WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process MC Front Row
WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
```

The player buttons (play, pause, exit) do not respond to the touch anymore, and at the end of the video the app freezes!

Comment: Wich device do you use? I’ve never seen this issue on my devices, but I got tow reports from users of my App, reporting that videos won’t play anymore. And both do use an iPad 4, the oldest iPad that is still supported by iOS 10. So this might be a bug in iOS 10, which only affects the old devices. The filter messages in the Xcode console are probably not related, because I do get these as well.

Comment: i got the same warning and in iOS 10 can't able to play video. :(

Comment: @alex: The issue is on iPhone, but not on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

The problem is related to a strange behavior with this method in the UIViewController on iPhone with iOS 10.0.1/

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    //SOME CODE
}
```

It seems that this method is called a thousand times during the video, on iPhone. 
I removed this method and now it works.

Comment: This would not work for me, because I do not implement this "viewWillLayoutSubviews" method at all. On the other hand, this might explain why the issue seems to occur only on the oldest and slowest devices (iPad 4) which do still support iOS 10. Maybe even the empty default method of the UIViewController class itself will eat up so much processor time when called thousands of times, that on these old and slow devices there#s not much time left for the video.